# How to replace an element in a LinkedList?

Tags: c#, .net, replace, linked-list

How do you replace an element in a Linked list in C#? While in java either can use set or add method to replace a particular element in the list... I can´t find how do I replace it in C#.

Comment: take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.80).aspx and http://www.dijksterhuis.org/using-linked-lists-in-c-part-ii/

Comment: By "a liked list" you mean the `LinkedList<T>` class, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace value 2 with 3:

```
LinkedList<int> ll;
ll.Find(2).Value = 3;
```

Comment: +1 Interesting. I interpreted "replace an element" as replacing a node, and you interpreted it as changing the value. I can't say that either interpretation is "right" or "wrong." But I like your solution better.

Answer (score 8):

There is no `Replace` method for a linked list node. To replace a node, you have to:

1. Find the node you want to replace.
2. Insert a new node before that node (`AddBefore`)
3. Remove the original node.

You could also use `AddAfter`. The result would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

With `LinkedList<T>` you work on `LinkedListNode<T>` items. `LinkedListNode<T>` has a `Value` property that you can use get or set a particular item.

Unlike c#, Java does not have the concept of properties integrated in the language. In Java you create properties by adding hand-made set_Property and get_Property methods. The c# properties can be accessed like fields.

Java:

```
obj.set_MyProperty(123);
x = obj.get_MyProperty();
```

c#:

```
obj.MyProperty = 123;
x = obj.MyProperty;
```

Internally however, c# calls getter and setter methods as well. You would declare a property like this in c#:

```
private int _myProperty;
public int MyProperty {
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set { _myProperty = value; }
}
```

In this special case, when no other logic is involved you can use automatically implemented properties:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

In your linked list, you would change the frst element of the list like this:

```
myLinkedList.Fist.Value = your new value;
```